# Передача данных между фрагментами

Tags: android, java, android-fragment

Здравствуйте!
В фрагменте (1) есть `ListView`, со списком юзеров. По нажатию на сотрудника, открывается другой фрагмент (2), с данными этого пользователя `ID, Name, LastName`. Как из фрагмента (1), передать в фрагмент (2) значения `id, name, lastName?`.

Отправляю вот так:

```
            Fragment f = new EmployeeDetails();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", "123");
            f.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);
            ft.commit();
```

Принимаю:

```
      etId.setText(getArguments().getString("ID")); //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
      Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
      etId.setText(bundle.getString("ID"));
```

Comment: покажите где и как вы определяете `etId`. он у вас null, а не аргументс.

Comment: А поставить точку останова и продебижаить нельзя?
я бы поставил условие и проверил равенсво null

Comment: А может быть у вас etId == null? вы проверяли?

Comment: У меня аналогичная ситуация, Null Exeption выдает

Answer (score 10, accepted):

После создания фрагмента, вызовом метода `setArguments()` передайте ему `Bundle` с нужными данными.

В самом фрагменте этот `Bundle` можно получить вызовом `getArguments()`.

Comment: @falstaf код добавил к ответу.

Answer (score 8):

Null может быть, если Вы дважды создаете фрагмент, который вызываете.

Я делаю так:

**Шаг 1:**

Во фрагменте источнике (откуда передавать):

```
Тело какого-то onClick {    
    YourFragmentClass yfc = new YourFragmentClass();    
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("tag", intInformation);
    yfc.setArguments(bundle);
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,  yfc).commit();
}
```

*Если строку*

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,  yfc).commit();
```

*изменить на*

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,  new YourFragmentClass()).commit();
```

*то bundle будет всегда пустой - null. И все потому, что фрагмент создается заново и к нему не был прикреплен bundle.*

**Шаг 2:**

Во фрагменте получателе (где получаем - YourFragmentClass):

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
      Integer recieveInfo = bundle.getInt("tag");
}
```