# Как получить значения с активной разметки?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Ситуация:
Есть две разметки, в которых присутствуют текстовые поля и две кнопки.

Логика кнопок одинакова для этих разметок, поэтому логично реализовать их в виде фрагмента.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "отправить" извлекались значения с той разметки, на которой сейчас находится пользователь (с текущей активной разметки)?

И как лучше реализовать данную задачу?

Разметка Fragment'a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Відправити"
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Назад"
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка 1
[image: img до розметки 1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/b04"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ім&apos;я:"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Ведіть ваше ім&apos;я"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="e-mail:"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clEmail"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Ведіть ваш e-mail"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Питання:"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clQuestion"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Ведіть ваше побажання/питання"
                android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
                android:lines="3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="****.ButtonSendActivity"
                android:id="@+id/fragment3"
                tools:layout="@layout/afr_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.ITuse.leofit.Support.ButtonOrderFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            tools:layout="@layout/afr_application_form_subscription" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка 2

[image: img до розметки 2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/b04"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/b04"
        android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">



        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ім&apos;я:"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Ведіть ваше ім&apos;я"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Прізвище"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clLastName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Ведіть ваше прізвище"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Телефон"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clPhone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Ведіть ваш номер телефону. \n Наприклад (093) 294 57 70"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="e-mail:"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clEmail"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="Ведіть ваш e-mail"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="****.ButtonSendActivity"
                android:id="@+id/fragment4"
                tools:layout="@layout/afr_button" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Добавьте код разметки и уточните вопрос, согласно этому коду. на данный момент вопрос сложен к пониманию.

Comment: Кнопки "Отправить" и "Назад" нужно реализовать в виде фрагмента, как я понял.
В данном случае, конечно, можно обойтись и без этого. Но подход правильный - всё, что можно повторно использовать - лучше использовать повторно, а не плодить лишние кнопки и панели.

Comment: Концептуально, фрагмент должен иметь доступ к данным, вносимым в поля формы. Соответственно, нужно сделать так, чтобы данные, вводимые пользователем "складировались" в некотором буфере, к которому имел бы доступ фрагмент. По событию изменения данных в поле ввода - данные заносятся в этот "буфер". А по событию нажатия на один из своих элементов (на кнопку "Отправить" или кнопку "Назад") - фрагмент берёт данные из буфера и в случае "Отправить" - отсылает данные пользователя на сервер, в случае "Назад" - берёт из буфер данные о прошлой активити (разметке) - направляет пользователя на неё.

Comment: Про обмен данными с фрагментами можно почитать тут: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php и тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326817/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8