# Краш диалога при передачи данных во фрагмент

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь передать данные по [этому примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326817/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) и в результате приложение падает.

```
public void startTimer(View v) {

    int vOtd = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("otd");
    int sec = vOtd * 1000;

    forTimer ft = new forTimer();
    Bundle bundleMin = new Bundle();
    bundleMin.putInt("sec", sec);
    ft.setArguments(bundleMin);
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(fragment3, ft).commit();

    DialogFragment newFragment = new timer();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timer");
}
```

Принимаю во фрагменте

```
Bundle bundleMin = getArguments();
if (bundleMin != null) {
    int rInfo = bundleMin.getInt("sec");
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

UPD

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle args) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_timer, null)).setPositiveButton(
            R.string.textButtonDialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            }
    ).setCancelable(false);

    ch=getView().findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    ch.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    ch.start();

    return builder.create();

}
```

Comment: А логи где? Добавьте их в вопрос

Comment: Аргументы устанавливаете в один фрагмент `forTimer`, диалог у вас другой фрагмент `timer`. Что-то тут не так. А принимаете в каком фрагменте? И да, добавьте стектрейс падения.

Comment: @eugeneek диалог timer содержит в себе фрагмент forTimer. forTimer принимает данные и запускается с диалогом

Comment: @Flippy падает на fm.beginTransaction().replace(fragment3, ft).commit(); думаю, что из за того, что я запускаю фрагмент совместно с диалогом который содержит этот же фрагмент. Есть идеи как передать данные во фрагмент не запуская его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте метод `newInstance` во фрагменте, в который будете передавать нужные параметры. Например, уровень прогресса для `ProgressBar` в окне. **Не переопределяйте конструктор фрагмента**

```
public static MyDialog newInstance(int levelProgress) {
    MyDialog instance = new MyDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(LEVEL_PROGRESS, text);
    instance.setArguments(args);
    return instance;
}
```

В `onCreateView` фрагмента нужно создавать `View` для диалога. Туда и приходит наш `Bundle`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    ProgressBar level = v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_level);
    int levelProgress = args.getInt(LEVEL_PROGRESS);
    level.setProgress(levelProgress);
    return v;
}
```

Или, в `onCreateDialog()`:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle args) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle("Alert")
        .setMessage("Уровень: " + args.getInt(LEVEL_PROGRESS));
    return alert.create();
}
```

`LEVEL_PROGRESS` это ключ для данных в `Bundle`. Вам нужно создать константу во фрагменте:

```
private static final String LEVEL_PROGRESS = "levelProgress";
```

Теперь можно использовать наш диалог так:

```
MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(50);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), /*тэг*/);
```

Транзакция происходит внутри метода `show`, вам о ней думать не надо. Тэгом может быть хоть что, если не надо, киньте `null`.

Comment: Не пойму, первая часть кода во фрагмент? Может быть в диалог? Вы наверно не правильно поняли. У меня активити с кнопкой, методом onClick запускается диалог, а диалог уже в свою очередь несет в себе фрагмент с таймером.

Comment: Если я пишу код во фрагмент. В той части кода где я вызываю диалог (т.е. в активити) не понимает newInstance. Перенес в диалог, ошибок не возникает но приложение падает.

Comment: @Лаврик Неизвестный, фрагмент в диалоге?

Comment: да, именно так, фрагмент в диалоге

Comment: А зачем вам писать свой велосипед, если есть `DialogFragment`? Это и диалог и фрагмент в одном. В ответе я его и привел

Comment: потому что Chronometr не хочет лезть в Dialog, а во фрагмент без проблем.

Comment: @Лаврик Неизвестный, эм. `DialogFragment` - наследник от `Fragment`. Не знаю что там за хронометр у вас, но вы видимо, что-то не так сделали

Comment: нет, он влез конечно, но не запускался с открытием диалога, и не реализовывался метод setOnChronometerTickListener

Comment: я добавил код хронометра в диалог. Посмотрите? (после строки UPD)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67769/discussion-between-flippy-and--).

Comment: все, сделал) спасибо за совет. Живи и процветай \\//_

Comment: подскажи, а если мне надо получить во фрагменте несколько строк? Как делать в таком случае?

Comment: Это мне нужно перписывать как впервом блоке код несколько раз? Или  есть какоето решение а-ля "через запятую"?